# Jetty WebSockets Error too large text

Tags: java, android, websocket, jetty

I'v using jetty 8.2.0 and getting this message sometimes, how can I enlarge max size of acceptable text?

```
WARN:oejw.WebSocketConnectionRFC6455:Text message too large > 16384 chars for SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@ac0d159 state=DATA buffer= g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@7337dff closed=false buffer=-1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I found one solution, but I'm not sure about that, maybe someone will send better solution

```
String urlConnect = "wss://test.test.com:11111/websocket";
WebSocket webSocket = new WebSocket.OnTextMessage() {...};

WebSocketClientFactory webSocketClientFactory = new WebSocketClientFactory();
webSocketClientFactory.setBufferSize(100000); //set this size as you need
webSocketClientFactory.start();

WebSocketClient webSocketClient = webSocketClientFactory.newWebSocketClient();
webSocketClient.setMaxBinaryMessageSize(100000);//set this size as you need
webSocketClient.setMaxTextMessageSize(100000);//set this size as you need
webSocketClient.open(URI.create(urlConnect), webSocket);
```